# Proof of a formula involving Gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

I am trying to prove the following formula for $\operatorname{Re} z>0$

$$\frac{\Gamma(z)\sin\theta z}{n(a^2+b^2)^{z/2}} = \int_0^\infty e^{-at^n}t^{nz-1} \sin(bt^n)\,dt$$

where $n$ is a positive integer, $a$ and $b$ are real numbers with $(a, b) \neq (0,0)$, and $\tan  = b/a$. When $a=0$, we take $\theta = \pm \pi/2$ such that $b>0$.

I used $\Gamma(z)= \int_0^\infty e^{-s}s^{z-1}\,ds$ with the substitution $s=(a+ib)t^n$ based on the given hint, but couldn't prove it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we notice that the given integral is equal to this:

$$I=\int_0^\infty e^{-at^n}t^{nz-1} \sin(bt^n)dt=\frac{1}{2i}\left[\int_0^\infty e^{-at^n}t^{nz-1}\left(e^{ibt^n}-e^{-ibt^n}\right)dt\right]$$

Rewriting gives:
$$\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty e^{(ib-a)t^n}t^{nz-1}dt-\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty e^{(-ib-a)t^n}t^{nz-1}dt$$

Then we do this substitution:
\begin{align}
c&=\pm ib-a\\
u&=-ct^n\\
du&=-nct^{n-1}dt
\end{align}
and rewrite the integral
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{ct^n}t^{nz-1}dt&=\int_0^\infty e^{ct^n}(t^n)^{z-1}t^{n-1}dt\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-u}\left(-\frac{u}{c}\right)^{z-1}\frac{-1}{nc}du\\
&=\frac{-1}{nc}\left(\frac{-1}{c}\right)^{z-1}\int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{z-1}du\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(z)}{n}(-c)^{-z}\\
\end{align}

Adding everything together and rewriting $a-ib=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{-i\theta}$ and $a+ib=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{i\theta}$:

\begin{align}
I&=\frac{\Gamma(z)}{2in}\left[(a-ib)^{-z}-(a+ib)^{-z}\right]\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(z)}{2in}\left[(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{-i\theta})^{-z}-(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{i\theta})^{-z}\right]\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(z)}{2in(a^2+b^2)^{z/2}}\left[(e^{-i\theta})^{-z}-(e^{i\theta})^{-z}\right]\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(z)}{2in(a^2+b^2)^{z/2}}\left[e^{iz\theta}-e^{-iz\theta}\right]\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(z)\sin(z\theta)}{n(a^2+b^2)^{z/2}}
\end{align}